# How to remove namespaces in the root element of the generated class file when using XSD files using XJC compiler

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

How to remove namespaces in the root element of the generated class file using XSD files using xjc plugin to compile. I am using JDK17 and Jakarta. I want to keep namespace only to the child elements but not to the root.

Below is the problem I am facing.

Expected request to be generated:

```
<Request xmlns="http://www.todo.com/services/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.todo.com/services/common/">
    <RootElement1>
        <ns2:ChildElement1>value1</ns2:ChildElement1>
        <ns2:ChildElement2>value2</ns2:ChildElement2>
        <ns2:ChildElement3>value3</ns2:ChildElement3>
        <ns2:ChildElement4>value4</ns2:ChildElement4>
        <ns2:ChildElement5>value5</ns2:ChildElement5>
    </RootElement1>
    <RootElement2>
        <ns2:ChildElement1>value1</ns2:ChildElement1>
        <ns2:ChildElement2>value2</ns2:ChildElement2>
        <ns2:ChildElement3>value3</ns2:ChildElement3>
        <ns2:ChildElement4>value4</ns2:ChildElement4>
    </RootElement2>
</Request>
```

Actual request generated

```
    <ns2:Request xmlns="http://www.todo.com/services/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.todo.com/services/common/">
        <ns2:RootElement1>
            <ChildElement1>value1</ChildElement1>
            <ChildElement2>value2</ChildElement2>
            <ChildElement3>value3</ChildElement3>
            <ChildElement4>value4</ChildElement4>
            <ChildElement5>value5</ChildElement5>
        </ns2:RootElement1>
        <ns2:RootElement2>
            <ChildElement1>value1</ChildElement1>
            <ChildElement2>value2</ChildElement2>
            <ChildElement3>value3</ChildElement3>
            <ChildElement4>value4</ChildElement4>
        </ns2:RootElement2>
    </ns2:Request>

My plugin settings looks like this in pom.xml

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <addGeneratedAnnotation>false</addGeneratedAnnotation>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>src/main/schema/xsd/binding.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/xsd/common.xsd</source>
                        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/schema/xsd/project.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/ebg</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My binding.xjb looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="3.0" xmlns:xjc="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:ifx="urn:ifxforum-org:XSD:1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="project.xsd" node="/xs:schema" >
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.sample.application.project">
            </jxb:package>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="common.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.sample.application.common" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```